# Customization of JFileChooser using UI Manager and Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, nimbus, uimanager

I am trying to override the Nimbus default color scheme of `JFileChooser`. I am using the following snippet to do that:

```
try {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
            defaults.put("Button.background",  new Color(240,230,140));
            defaults.put("OptionPane.background",Color.white);
            defaults.put("Panel.background",Color.white);
            defaults.put("Frame.background",Color.white);
            defaults.put("FileChooser.background",Color.white);
            break;
        }
    }
} 
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

This code is just changing the background color of the panels rather than the complete `JFileChooser`. Also it is not overriding the background color of the okay button. Here is the snapshot of the `JFileChooser` hence formed:

[image: Screenshot]